# constant pointers C++ and optimization, are they faster?

Tags: c++, arrays, performance, pointers, constants

I wounder if

- a constant pointer is faster or slower than a normal pointer? (a constant pointer is a pointer that one cannot change its address) declared as, int* const x;

  - a pointer to a constant int is faster than a pointer to an int? const int *x;
  - a constant pointer to a constant int is faster than a pointer to an int? e.g 
    int const * const x; int* y; ...so, would x be faster than y? (if they are used in array indexing)

Cheers,

Comment: I have yet to see a non-contrived example where this is the cast. Actually, I can not even come up quickly with a contrived one.

Answer (score 3):

They maybe faster but they don't not necessarily have to be.
The bottomline is that use const correctness to prevent honest programmers from making mistakes and making your code more intuitive rather than for enhancing performance. Most modern compilers will take care of it automagically.

Comment: Well, I am extracting a pointer from an object to play with it (I know that this is a bad programming practice, but, this is the only way for me to ensure more efficiency); thus, I am thinking to use const with it. If that, however, hinders the performance, I might omit it (the const) If I can gain more speed with the non-const pointer.  I will, of course, have to be very careful with the pointer. As I said, it points to a large array allocated in the heap.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, the compiler doesn't "pay attention" to whether something is `const` or not, it uses other heuristics to determine if a pointer needs reloading between use or not.

Certainly, if you have a function that takes a pointer as argument, it will make absolutely no difference. If you have a global variable that you use, then the compiler MAY consider "well, it's `const`, so I won't reload it every time". But it's very unlikely that it will actually make a difference. Parallel changes of a pointer is UB anyway (you should use atomic variables for that). If a function is called in the middle of the code, and the compiler can't inline [or "follow"] the function, it will most likely have to reload the pointer anyway.